# Junit test case not compiling on the fly in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, mockito, powermockito

I am writing junit using mockito, powermock API's. every time I need run maven command to compile my project to execute every single line code change in my test case. WHy this is happening . Eclipse should auto compile right on the fly, and simply I must be able to do run as Junit test case

Comment: is build automatically enabled? verify that Project > Build Automatically is enabled

Comment: Yes. it is enabled

Comment: what is the error message when you run the unit test from the test class?

Comment: I don't get error message. every time , I need to run mvn clean install / mvn clean test for even single line of code change. Why its not auto-compiling on the fly to speed up my junit test case writing

Answer (score 1):

I had tested and tried many, but unfortunately without success (Build Path check,  enable project build automatically, ...)

The following workaround worked for me:

1. Delete the project from eclipse
2. Remove the following files from the project folder on file system:
   **.settings (folder), .classpath, .project, .factorypath**
3. reimport the project as maven project again